# phpmyadmin - custom export-script - permission

Tags: phpmyadmin, export

**[SITUATION]**
im currently working on a database in **phpmyadmin**, running on a **raspberry pi 3**. I want to export data after customizing them, so I implemented a custom export script that handles the data I want to export in a specific way:

The data in the database holds errorcodes. I have a xml-file that has the errorcodes an their corresponding human-readable text to these errors. In the end the errorcodes AND the corresponding text should be exported.

**[PROBLEM]**
I cannot "find" the xml file when it is located outside of `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/`. If i put the xml file somewhere inside this directory (e.g. `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/myErrorcodes.xml`),  then `fileexists("/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/myErrorcodes.xml")` returns `TRUE`.

If the file is located somewhere else, e.g. `/home/pi/myErrorcodes.xml` the function `file_exists("/home/pi/myErrorcodes.xml")` returns `FALSE`.

**[QUESTIONS]**
How does phpmyadmin get its permissions set (why can it read in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` and its subdirectories but not anywhere else)? How can I tell phpmyadmin to have permissions to read somewhere else on the system except his install folder? I would like to NOT put the xml inside phpmyadmin's folder in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` because it is used by some other applications (read-only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deep for some time I found the config you need to change/add.

phpmyadmin runs under apache and so there is the config file `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`.

There you need to add the desired path where the xml is located (or one of the parent directories) to the line
`php_admin_value open_basedir /etc/phpmyadmin/:/dir/where/xml/islocated/:...`